# How to select specific row and click on delete for that row

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a table that has some columns and last column has an image for delete and it display delete confirmation first.

I know how to respond to javascript prompt like this

```
    IAlert simpleAlert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    simpleAlert.Accept();
```

However I dont know how to delete any of available rows in the table by clicking in the delete image

here is the delete image markup look like

```
<a id="delete34" href="delxxx?id=34" onclick="return prompt('del34')"><img src="img/delete_24.png" alt="delete" title="delete" width="24" height="24"/></a>
```

The last number "34" is the id of the row and that generated dynamically so how I target any available row and click on delete image ?

Comment: To be clear, you want a generic way to click on the delete button on a row in the table. Is that correct? If so, how do you plan on choosing the row?

Comment: @Haendler Yes my problem I can not find anyway to target any row to test delete. There is no ID hidden tag in the page and I can not figure it out

Comment: An url you could give?

Comment: So, you don't care which row you press delete on, you just want to find one and click it to test that the delete function works?

Comment: Sorry Kanak I can not post url

Comment: Yes Haendler just to test delete

Comment: Ok, this is what I've found that works in my application. Make sure that you are in the right iframe (the app I'm working on LOVES iframes and iframes within iframes). Then use the css selector or xpath (I've had more success with css for this) to find the element and click it. It should look something like this.

            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#menuTable > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")).Click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
IList<IWebElement> rowDeleteButtons = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(@id,'delete')]");

rowDeleteButtons[0].Click();
```

should do the trick. Since the row id is not important, this will always work if you have at least one row.

Comment: If you are always going to pick the first one, just use `.FindElement()` and click on it, e.g. `driver.findElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@id,'delete')]").click();`

Comment: That's not a real good approach. Although it might work, findElement should be used for single, unique elements and findElements for multiple elements, so that your code is self explanatory and reflects what it's actually doing.

Comment: No. `.FindElement()` is for returning the first element that matches the locator while `.FindElements()` is for returning a collection of elements... 0, 1, or more. For example, best practice to determine if an element exists or not is to use `.FindElements()` and check to see if the collection is empty. Why would you package up a collection of elements only to ever use the first one? That's not self explanatory... that's confusing.

Comment: This doesn't work if the page refreshes on a delete. After the first deleted element  you will get a `StaleElementReferenceException`. For each web element, you must call whichever "find" mechanism you use to obtain it and then delete it.